# rails text_area format for javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

An attribute of type `text` needs to be generated within a javascript.

Some records have carriage returns inserted by the user and these need to be passed to javascript in form `\n`.  However when I place

```
<%= uc.main_text %>
```

within the javascript, it returns carriage returns

```
Salties at bottom...

what happens here I am not certain
```

when  `\n` is needed.

```
Salties at bottom...\n\nwhat happens here I am not certain
```

From the console calling the attribute returns a proper string

```
uc.main_text
[...] \r\n\r\n [...]
```

How can this be transposed for use by the javascript?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please provide more information.

Comment: `\r\n\r\n` is needed in the rendered javascript, not carriage returns.

Comment: That doesn't help. Please share what HTML you expect for an example text.

Comment: javascript escape is required to make this function `<%= j (uc.main_text) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`#escape_javascript`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript):

```
string = "Salties at bottom...

what \"happens\" here I 'am' not certain"
puts %{var string = "#{escape_javascript(string)}"}
```

This will print:

```
var string = "Salties at bottom...\n\nwhat \"happens\" here I \'am\' not certain"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw), if I understood your question right.